# iOS7 bounds of window misplaced on iPhone5

Tags: iphone, ios7

Some wierd stuff is going on in a app that i recently took over development of. For some reason, when i launch the app with simulator iPhone retina (4-inch) the app launches like this:

[image: two muppets]

In the story board, the views look correct when i change to iPhone5.

I just dragged out a clean controller and set it as the initial one, so no messed up code in the controllers should cause this.

What am I missing?!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the fact that the app is not optimized for iPhone 5. It is as easy as setting the correct launch image - `Default-568h@2x.png`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a Retina 4 launch image. `Default-568h@2x.png` is required to run at native resolution on retina 4 devices.

[image]